# .htaccess redirect with unique url AND query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to redirect:

```
/category/unique-name?foo=123&bar=&abc=
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/new/page
```

The majority of the articles I've read hint towards redirecting a query string pattern for multiple pages. I'm just after the one page that needs a redirect.

My latest attempt looks like this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/unique-name/$
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) $ http://www.example.com/new/page? [R=301,L]
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE 07/04/2017**

Thanks for all of the suggestions. I've tried them all, some resulted in an Error 500, some had no effect. I've listed which are which below...

**# NO CHANGE**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/unique-name$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/new/page [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/unique-name$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/new/page [R=301,L]
```

**# ERROR 500**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^/?category/unique-name/?$ $ http://www.example.com/new/page? [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/unique-name/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^ $ http://www.example.com/new/page [R=301,END,QSD]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^/?category/unique-name/?$ $ http://www.example.com/new/page [R=301,END,QSD]
```

Comment: I tried the suggestions below and updated the initial post with my results ^^^

Comment: "didn't work" does not help, you will have to tell us more details. 1. please post the _exact_ URL requested that lead to your results from your http servers access log file, 2. post the entries you receive in the http servers error log file in case you receive an http status 500.

Comment: Also please specify what version of the http server you actually operate. I suspect it is a very old one.

Comment: I ask about the _specific_ URLs (not replacements) since all this looks like there is no real issue with the suggestions, but with the specific, real world data you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/unique-name$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/new/page [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: After some trying, it worked for me, but I had to do two steps: 1) put the code at the start of the htaccess; 2) put a `?` after the http://www.example.com/new/page otherwise the query string will be added again to the URL and it will cause a redirect loop

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is close to perfect. Have a try with one of these two only slightly modified alternatives:

Approach 1 (old):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/unique-name/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^ $ http://www.example.com/new/page? [R=301,L]
```

Approach 2 (old):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^/?category/unique-name/?$ $ http://www.example.com/new/page? [R=301,L]
```

---

In case you operate a not too outdated version of the apache http server you can implement a slightly cleaner final URL:

Approach 1 (new):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/category/unique-name/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^ $ http://www.example.com/new/page [R=301,END,QSD]
```

Approach 2 (new):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^foo=123&bar=&abc=$
RewriteRule ^/?category/unique-name/?$ $ http://www.example.com/new/page [R=301,END,QSD]
```

If these lead to an http status 500 (internal server error), then chances are that indeed your version of the http server is too old and you have to stick to the work around shown in the first two approaches.

---

However looking at the fact that you implement an *external* redirection (`R=301`) I wonder if that will work and actually implements what you are trying to achieve...

Your own attempt (and the modified version above) rewrite an incoming request with those get parameters externally to the clean URL. So they change the URL visible in the browser. Which is pretty and fine, *but*: Is your setup actually able to process the next incoming request to `/new/page`?

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately they didn't work. I've updated my post with the results from each of your options.